# Problem in compilation

Tags: lyx, compiling, titlesec

The following is present in the preamble of the LyX document that I am working upon. Everything is fine but when I use `titlesec` package it does not compile when I have a numbered equation. Gives an error that `I can't use \eqno in math mode`. The document gets compiled when I remove `titlesec`. There is also no issue if I change the equation mode to an inline. I use Report class with Times New Roman font.

This is the output for the ex file which has the numbered equation.

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.1.4 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,english]{report}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[paperwidth=210mm,paperheight=297mm]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=30mm,bmargin=22mm,lmargin=20mm,rmargin=30mm,headheight=3mm,headsep=12mm,footskip=10mm}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\AtBeginDocument{\newgeometry{hmargin=4cm}}
\raggedbottom
\pagenumbering{roman}
\geometry{textheight=245mm, textwidth=160mm, footskip=10mm}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\fontsize{16}{18}\selectfont}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{-8pt}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{-12pt}
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{-12pt}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecfont{\fontsize{8}{12}\selectfont}
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{-12pt}
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsecfont{\fontsize{8}{12}\selectfont}
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsubsecskip}{-12pt}

\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\fontseries{md}\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\fontseries{md}\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecfont}{\fontseries{md}\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}

\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\fontseries{md}\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecpagefont}{\fontseries{md}\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecpagefont}{\fontseries{md}\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{15mm}{\LARGE}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0mm}{50mm}{15mm}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{15mm}{15mm}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{15mm}{15mm}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{Chapter\space{\thechapter,\space\space}Section\space{\thesection}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\chapter{\noindent \fontsize{18}{22}\selectfont Introduction}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}


\section{Background}

\noindent leading to the rich variety of vivid and beautiful colors.
It took 


\paragraph*{\noindent \textmd{
\begin{equation}
m_{i}\frac{d^{2}x_{i}}{dt^{2}}=-\bigtriangledown_{i}V\left(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},.....,x_{N}\right),\,\left(i\:=1...N\right)
\end{equation}
Here }$m_{i}$ \textmd{is the mass of the $ith$ atom} \textmd{whose
position at time $t$ is} $x_{i}$. }
\end{document}
```

This is document for the ex2 file which has an inline equation.

```
%% LyX 2.1.4 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,english]{report}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[paperwidth=210mm,paperheight=297mm]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=30mm,bmargin=22mm,lmargin=20mm,rmargin=30mm,headheight=3mm,headsep=12mm,footskip=10mm}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\AtBeginDocument{\newgeometry{hmargin=4cm}}
\raggedbottom
\pagenumbering{roman}
\geometry{textheight=245mm, textwidth=160mm, footskip=10mm}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\fontsize{16}{18}\selectfont}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{-8pt}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{-12pt}
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{-12pt}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecfont{\fontsize{8}{12}\selectfont}
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{-12pt}
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsecfont{\fontsize{8}{12}\selectfont}
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsubsecskip}{-12pt}

\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\fontseries{md}\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\fontseries{md}\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecfont}{\fontseries{md}\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}

\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\fontseries{md}\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecpagefont}{\fontseries{md}\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecpagefont}{\fontseries{md}\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{15mm}{\LARGE}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0mm}{50mm}{15mm}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{15mm}{15mm}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{15mm}{15mm}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{Chapter\space{\thechapter,\space\space}Section\space{\thesection}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\chapter{\noindent \fontsize{18}{22}\selectfont Introduction}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}


\section{Background}


\paragraph*{\noindent \textmd{the type of interatomic potential $V$ used to
simulate the material properties.$m_{i}\frac{d^{2}x_{i}}{dt^{2}}=-\bigtriangledown_{i}V\left(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},.....,x_{N}\right),\,\left(i\:=1...N\right)$Here
}$m_{i}$ \textmd{is the mass of the $ith$ atom} \textmd{whose position
at time $t$ is} $x_{i}$.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of just showing the preamble, can you make a minimal document (http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample) demonstrating the problem? Add either the complete LyX file (it is a text file, so open it in a text editor, and copy-paste everything), or the complete LaTeX code (View --> Source pane, choose *Complete document* in the dropdown menu on the right side of the output pane, copy-paste everything) to your question.

Comment: Here is the link for the tex files that I have generated.      http://dropcanvas.com/m4j7y                                                                                                                ex.tex is generated when the formula is numbered one. 

ex2.tex is generated when it's an inline one.                                     The code gets compiled when the equation is inline but not for the numbered one.

Comment: Can't you include the code in your question, instead of using an external link?

Comment: I have done that.

Comment: The *Paragraph* style from the drop down menu on the top left of LyX is *not* meant for the text of a paragraph, i.e. it is not the same as `<p>...</p>` in HTML (if you're familiar with that). It is a section heading, one step below `subsection` in the hierarchy (e.g. like `<h4> .. </h4>` in HTML). Use the *Standard* style for normal text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using the *Paragraph* style in  LyX wrongly. I'm referring here to the styles from the dropdown menu in the top left of LyX:

[image]

All the entries grouped under *Sectioning* and *Unnumbered* are *section headings*. You seem to have used the unnumbered *Paragraph** for normal text, which is just wrong, whether it's intentional or not. For normal text use the *Standard* style.